# Searching '$' character in SQL query

Tags: sql, impala

How can I search for "$" special character in SQL query?

I'm trying to get hosts ended by $ character. This is Apache Impala.

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(host) FROM dclogwindows WHERE host LIKE '%[\$]'
```

But I get:

```
Done. 0 results.
```

Tried too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(host) FROM dclogwindows WHERE host LIKE '%$'
```

But same results

In a global search I see many hosts like this:

```
SELECT host FROM dclogwindows

H3932924934$
M4234278281$
M4545656543$ ...
```

No matter what I do, if I use a dollar symbol, results are 0.

Tried `'%$%'`, tried ilike, tried `'%$'`

Explorer version: Hue™ 3.11 - IU de Hadoop

Comment: Your matching syntax is incorrect, but $ is not a special character in SQL anyway.  WHERE host LIKE '%$' should suffice.

Comment: `LIKE '%$'` - the `[]` has no meaning in a SQL LIKE expression

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` and `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: @Nand0san . . . Where are you writing your query?  I think the problem is at that level, not in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape anything.  The following should work:

```
WHERE host LIKE '%$'
```

`'$'` is not a special character in `LIKE` patterns.  In most databases, only `'%'` and `'_'` are.  Sometimes, `'\'`, `'['`, `']'`, and `'*'` are depending on the database.

EDIT:

Your problem is probably in the interface level.  I'm not sure how to escape the value there.  Perhaps:

```
WHERE host LIKE '%\$'
```

Comment: I tried, but this is Apache Impala and don't get any results. Add data to my first question

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Brave Browser was the problem, using Firefox the query works right.

I uninstalled Brave and reinstalled without any **extensions** and it works too.

I think it was "MetaMask" extension, but I am not able to repeat the error with a new installation of MetaMask

Thank U everybody